# Data won't post correctly

Tags: google-apps-script, salesforce, http-post, soql, urlfetch

I'm trying to use Google Apps Scripts to post to Salesforce to create a new account. I'm able to use my credentials fine to query with SOQL. When I try to post, it basically returns data as if I'm describing the Account, and the new account doesn't get created. I tried using the workbench rest API with this payload and can create an account no problem, so I know it's not an issue with fields/values.

```
function pushToSalesforce(){
  var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
  var instance_url = "https://na9.salesforce.com";
  var access_token = userProperties.getProperty('access_token');
 
  var payload = {
    "Name" : "testaccount",
    "Website" : "testaccountstuff.com",
    "Platform__c" : "API",
    "Industry" : "Apparel"
  };
  
  var queryUrl = instance_url + '/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/account/';
  
  var headers = 
      { 
        "method" : "POST",
        "contentType" : "application/json",
        "payload": JSON.stringify(payload),
        "headers": {
          "Authorization" : "Bearer "+access_token,
          "Accept": "application/json"
        }
      };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(queryUrl, headers);
}
```

I'm going nuts trying to figure out what the issue is. Anybody have an idea?

Comment: Use httpbin.org/post to see what gets posted and how is it different from the rest api.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your app is making a `GET` instead of `POST`. Is this language / HTTP library case-sensitive? [Documentation seems to use lowercase](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

You are supposed to send a `POST` to `/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Account` (you're using very old API version but that shouldn't matter). What exactly do you see in response? It may look "describe'ish" but it's unlikely to be a real describe result unless you explicitly call `/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Account/describe`.

A `GET` call to `/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Account` is a discovery, a way for the API to self-document. Returns very basic info about the object, something like

```
{
  "objectDescribe" : {
    "activateable" : false,
    "createable" : true,
    "custom" : false,
    (... snip...)
    "updateable" : true,
    "urls" : {
      "compactLayouts" : "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/describe/compactLayouts",
      "rowTemplate" : "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/{ID}",
      "approvalLayouts" : "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/describe/approvalLayouts",
      "defaultValues" : "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/defaultValues?recordTypeId&fields",
      "listviews" : "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/listviews",
      "describe" : "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/describe",
      "quickActions" : "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/quickActions",
      "layouts" : "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/describe/layouts",
      "sobject" : "/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account"
    }
  },
  "recentItems" : [ ]
}
```

A proper describe call would instead return info about all columns you can see in the table, all relations (foreign keys) to this object...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my actual script was the "my domain" custom instance_url for my company (but didn't want to broadcast it), e.g. "https://companyname.lightning.force.com". I tried using my server instance "na85" instead and it worked fine! Super weird because I have another function using the other instance_url with a GET and it worked no problem. Thanks for your help!